# Getting error: Found argument '--target-signer' while running parity bridges common

Tags: polkadot, parity-bridges-common

Error: Getting error while following the Parity Bridges common code on github. Got this error while trying to send message.
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynJzD.png)

Error:
error: Found argument '--target-signer' which wasn't expected, or isn't valid in this context

USAGE:
substrate-relay send-message  --source-host  --source-port  --source-signer

Comment: Update or switch your git repo. That's how this is gonna solve

Answer (score 1):

Check the fn send-message in the send-message.rs of bin-substrate folder. You can add the target-signer for particular message-dispatch.